# Given that a man is of genotype Aa, the probability that his brother is of the same genotype is Aa (1+pq)/2.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have the following problem: Given that a man is of genotype Aa, the probability that his brother is of the same genotype is Aa  $(1+pq)/2$.

First, I have they are from a population where the genotype frequencies are $u=p^2, 2v = 2pq, w=q^2$ with $p+q=1$ (such characterization given by Hardy's Law of populations genetics). Then, I see that the problem is a conditional probability, because I need to find the probability of the brother being Aa (event A) given that the man is Aa (event H). Then I know that $P(A|H) = P(AH)/P(H)$.

However, I can't seem to understand how to compute $P(AH)$. I know that $P(H) = 2pq$ because it's the probability of any man having Aa, but how can I compute the probability of both brothers being Aa? I would be glad if you showed me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ \{F,M\}\ $ is the multiset of the genotypes of the brothers' parents, then
$$
P(AH)=\sum_{g=G} P(AH|\{F,M\}=g)P(\{F,M\}=g)\ ,
$$
where $\ G\ $ is the set of all possible genotype pairs.

The possible genotype pairs of the parents are listed in the first column of the following table, the probabilities of those genotype pairs are listed in the second column, the conditional probabilities of the first son having genotype $\ Aa\ $ are listed in the third, and the conditional probabilities of both sons having genotype $\ Aa\ $ are listed in the fourth.  Since the events that the sons have any particular genotype are conditionally independent given the parents' genotype pair, this latter conditional probability is just the square of the former.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
g&P(\{F,M\}=g)&P(H|\{F,M\}=g)&P(AH|\{F,M\}=g)\\
\hline
\{2AA\}&p^4&0&0\\
\{AA,Aa\}&4p^3q&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}\\\
\{AA,aa\}&2p^2q^2&1&1\\
\{2Aa\}&4p^2q^2&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}\\
\{Aa,aa\}&4pq^3&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}\\
\{2aa\}&q^4&0&0\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Thus,
\begin{align}
P(AH)&=p^3q+3p^2q^2+pq^3\\
&=pq\big(p^2+3pq+q^2\big)\\
&=pq(1+pq)\ ,
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
P(AH|H)=\frac{1+pq}{2}\ .
$$